# PopupWindows are shown in reversed order after application is resumed

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

On devices with Android >= 4.4.2 I've faced a strange behavior of popupWindows.

If more than 1 window is opened, and you switch to another application, then after you resume first application, all popupWindows will be shown in the reversed order (I mean if you had window1, window2 on top of window1, and window3 on top of previous two, then after app is resumed, you will have window3, window2, window1).

Earlier versions (< 4.4.2) doesn't have this bug (or maybe it is not a bug, and this is supposed to be correct behavior?). And to my shame, I have no idea how to fix this in my app. I appreciate if any can help.